# How to find the latest status of a resource if the resource has a event in given timeframe?

Tags: postgresql

I have a DB table that has columns: UUID, resource_UUID, event_type, created_ts, ....
I have given a timeframe startDate - endDate i need to find the latest status the given resource had within the timeframe.

My idea is to find the last event the resource has in the timeframe, and then based on event_type i need to do 1 of the following:

1. If event_type is INSPECTION, then find corresbonding inspection and just take status and carry on
2. If event type is REVOCATION or BLACKLIST then count this as status and carry on
3. If event type is UNDO_REVOCATION or DEBLACKLIST then find the latest event that came before the corresbonding REVOCATION or BLACKLIST and find the status based on that.
4. If its anything else then find the first occurance of any of the previous 3

This is quite the diverging flow and i have no idea how to solve this. How should i tackle this issue? The end result should be a list of distinct resource_uuid-s with their last activ status within the timeframe.

EDIT 1

For example i have dta in the format

UUID1, ResUUID1, INSPECTION, someDate

UUID2, ResUUID1, VERIFICATION, someDate

UUID3, ResUUID1, BLACKLIST, someDate

UUID4, ResUUID2, INSPECTION, someDate

UUID5, ResUUID3, INSPECTION, someDate

UUID6, ResUUID4, INSPECTION, someDate

etc
where event_Type is one of the following (INSPECTION, BLACKLIST, REVOKATION, DEBLACKLIST, UNDO_REVOCATION, VERIFICATION)

Now the query needs to go over the table and find what is the active status given a timeframe. Show only resources that have atleast 1 event in time frame, so for status calculation you can look at data before the timeframe but not after.

Now for the conditions:

1. If last event is VERIFICATION with marking uninspected, status = UNINSPECTED
2. If last event is BLACKLIST, status = BLACKLIST
3. If last event is REVOKATION, status = REVOKED
4. If last event is INSPECTION, status = inspection status from inspection table
5. If last event is DEBLACKLIST, find first event that is not blacklist and determine status based on that. Exception: if only other event is blacklist, then after DELACKLIST status = UNINSPECTED
6. If last event is UNDO_REVOKATION find firs event that is not REVOKATION and determine status based on that.
7. If last event is anything else, find first event you can use to determine status.
8. Is status is not UNINSPECTED, BLACK or REVOKED, check the expiery state of last active INSPECTION within the timeframe. If expiery is less than end of timeframe, status = EXPIRED

Priorities of statuses

1. UNINSPECTED
2. BLACK
3. REVOKED
4. EXPIRED
5. Whatever the inspection status is

Expected output is a table

resource_uuid, active status inside the timframe

resource_uuid1 , BLACK

resource_uuid2, GREEN

resource_uuid3, UNINSPECTED

etc

Comment: You need to elaborate further on the problem you have. Maybe sample data and expected result could help us understanding what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Example data is hard as i need to create ALOT of it for this query to make any sense. But i tried to elaborate on my requirements.